# How do I create an interactive shiny doc via rmd file on github?

Tags: r, download, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I have an interactive shiny doc .Rmd file (+ a .png file it loads) saved on GitHub.

I want 100 students to be able to quickly open this .Rmd file *directly from* GitHub so that they can follow along on their own machines.

- I want to avoid having to deal with the mess of assigning working directories etc.

**Is there a easy way to source the .Rmd file (or any R script) from GitHub** using just base R packages?

- base R because I have to assume that these users just downloaded R and don't yet know how to download packages (and teaching them is not the point of the lesson).

I tried `eval(parse(text = readLines(website_url))`, but I get an `unepected '<'` error for html tagging `<` symbols.

Example Code:

```
---
title: "Help Me"
output:  html_document
runtime: shiny
---
<style type="text/css">
h1.title {
  font-size: 55px;
  font-family: "Arial MT";
  text-align: center;
}
```

The above does not work when `eval(pasrse())`'d, but works fine when entered directly in RStudio.

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/runUrl.html does this work for you? didn't test form markdowns so not submitting as an answer

Comment: why not just host it for them?

Comment: @Nate Well I have the doc on shinyApps.io, but I have no way to test if it will work for 100s of people at once (which is what I need), and I would like to have a backup in case that approach fails. (This is for a workshop).

Comment: @OganM doesn't appear to work since those functions are strictly for Shiny,not for interpreting/reading knitr code.

Comment: there is an easy way to host the Rmd pages for free on github.pages, I'm sure that would handle the traffic and I bet shinyApps.io can hang in there too. Maybe using Rpubs as an easy back up option too

Comment: by the way linking to a sample file (especially when you get a specific error like that) can be helpful for people who try to offer solutions. parse/eval won't work with markdown files as they are not R code. But if you had a file that run's the interactive markdown file and ran that through `eval` or `source` that would work. Here's what I use to source files from github https://github.com/oganm/ogbox/blob/master/R/sourceWeb.R#L8-L32